# Quantum analogue of Wiener process

Tags: pr.probability

The Wiener process (say, on $\mathbb{R}$) can be thought of as a scaling limit of a classical, discrete random walk. On the other hand, one can define and study *quantum random walks*, when the underlying stochastic process is governed by a unitary transform + measurement (for an excellent introduction, see http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303081).

My question is - do quantum random walks have a reasonable continuous limit, something which would give a quantum analogue of the Wiener process?

Comment: http://www.iop.org/EJ/abstract/1751-8121/40/45/016

Answer (score 3):

I believe that The theory of [quantum sochastic processes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuantumStochasticCalculus.html) of Hudson and Parthasarathy,
(see the original [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-93/issue-3/Quantum-Itos-formula-and-stochastic-evolutions/cmp/1103941122.full)) provides the necessary generalization to the continuous limit and also to a more general quantum evolution semigroups.

Answer (score 2):

In section III.B of the survey paper you cite, it describes *continuous quantum walks*, which are I think are a natural analogue of the Wiener process.  These are basically Hamiltonian evolution when the Hamiltonian is something like the adjacency matrix (or Laplacian) of a graph.

[On the relationship between continuous- and discrete-time quantum walk](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0312) has some recent developments with fascinating applications to simulating Hamiltonians on quantum computers.